# Git Bash Inserts Tilde

Tags: vim, git-bash

Does anyone know what could be causing git bash to randomly insert the tilde character in the terminal window.

Also I am not sure if related, but when viewing log files in vim, the help dialog automatically opens in a split window in vim.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?  I suspect it could be some sort of keep alive setting, but I have yet to figure this one out.

Comment: This might be a question where a screenshot would be helpful. Although it's possible that it's just the default of git-bash opening in the home directory, which is indicated by the ~ character.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Same as above answer.

Caffeine was causing it for me.
What I did was add a command argument `-useshift` and this stopped it completely.

For more command line things:  [Caffeine command line arguments](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/)

Comment: I believe that you can also edit your `~/.inputrc` file with `"\e[28~":""` to eat the F15 key inside the `git bash` or MSYS2 window.  See https://superuser.com/a/987505/82189

Comment: For the google indexes, I'll also mention I have seen this "random" tilde with SecureCRT.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer to the issue from  https://superuser.com/questions/708511/putty-inserts-random-characters-during-a-session 
I had also just installed Caffeine about a month ago, and that is when the symptoms began! Now that I have it disabled the symptoms above have gone away!

Answer (score 0):

caffeine -STES in the shortcut did it for me.